# SimpleDateFormat - Unparseable?

Tags: java, date, format

Take a look at my code:

```
 try {
           // String date = "30Jul2013";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date d = sdf.parse(date);

            SimpleDateFormat nsdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String nd = nsdf.format(d);
            System.out.println(nd);

            return nd;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Im am getting a error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-07-30 10:58:55.171"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
```

I would like to have an output of July 30, 2013 11:10 AM from the simpledateformat. There's LOCALE in my code. So what else should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to parse a string that is nothing like your format, and it's telling you that.

Comment: Your code should give you expected result when you uncomment the commented line.

Comment: My apologies the format of the date I am trying to parse is not the commented line but this one: Unparseable date: "2013-07-30 11:38:46.296"

Comment: @user2510841 So your format is completely wrong then. Why did you define your format to be ddMMMyyyy, when you're looking for yyyy-MM-dd etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
 try {
        // String date = "30Jul2013";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date d = sdf.parse(date);
```

Your date String variable line is commented out, so who's to know what String you're parsing? -- the JVM that's who.

As Robert Harvey points out, the String that you're actually trying to parse is printed for you in the exception message. If you print that String before you parse you'll also see that it's not what you expect it is and that the compiler's right.

In sum, you are somehow expecting that your sdf SimpleDateFormat object is formatting a String of a format similar to "30Jul2013", but the JVM is telling you that this simply is not so, that the String you are trying to parse in fact looks nothing like this, but rather is "2013-07-30 10:58:55.171".

Comment: The error message is already printing the string being parsed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I know that, and you know that, but the OP doesn't. It looks to be the default `toString()` for a Date object.

Comment: Well, now we all know.

Comment: Alright, how 'bout we get to the meat of it?  Does `2013-07-30 10:58:55.171` match the mask `MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm a`?

Comment: My apologies the format of the date I am trying to parse is not the commented line but this one:  Unparseable date: "2013-07-30 11:38:46.296"

Comment: I am actually passing a variable name date

Comment: Does `2013-07-30 11:38:46.296` match the mask `MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm a`?  For that matter, does it match `ddMMMyyyy`?

Comment: I don't think if the original format i am trying to parse matches my desired format.

Comment: This is the parameter i am getting from my query 2013-07-30 11:54:30:797000

Comment: C'mon, man.  Figure it out.  Read the docs.  Understand that even if it matches the second parse, it probably won't match the first one.

Comment: This is why I am asking. Meaning there's no way I can achieve my desired format?

Comment: Are you sure you have read this, in its entirety?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html  ... It says that you need `s` to capture the seconds, and I don't see that in your code.

Comment: @user2510841: of course there's a way. Study up on use of SimpleDateFormat and then try to write your code. You look like you're just borrowing code from somewhere and expect that it will work and are surprised when it doesn't, but it doesn't work that way. Check out Robert's link above to see the simple rules that you will need to apply.